# How to detect if the input csv file has embedded quotes?

Tags: java, regex, file, csv

I am writing a tool that takes an input a csv file and creates a new csv file as output with some fields modified. In some cases the input csv file has embedded quotes before and after the comma for example: "a","b","c", while in other cases I have directly a,b,c. The problem I am having is that if the input csv file has embedded quotes then I want the generated csv file should have the same embedded quotes. I am aware that I can control this settings in the constructor of the CSVWriter as follows:

```
CSVWriter writer = 
    new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(csv), ',', CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER)
```

But how to detect which case we have? Should I write a regex that counts the number of quote characters and compare it with the count of the , and see if it is more than double? for example "a","b","c" has 6 quotes and 2 commas.

Comment: It is often the case that only those strings with commas are quoted. E.g. *Hello, World* may appear as `"Hello, World"` but *Hello World* would not. I suspect you should control the quotes on a per-field basis.

Comment: actually in the files I have, it is either the whole rows have embedded quotes or no embedded quotes at all

Comment: Is the problem per row or per file ? Also, can you have a row with quotes that don't count as embedded ?

Comment: The problem is per file, if the input csv file has embedded quotes for all rows, then I want the output csv file to have same pattern, i.e. preserve these embedded quotes

Comment: Why don't you use an existing library like http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/ or https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/ ? It handles that already for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try [uniVocity-parsers](http://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial) to detect the format:

```
CsvParserSettings parserSettings = new CsvParserSettings(); //many options here, check the tutorial.
parserSettings.detectFormatAutomatically();

CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(parserSettings);

//parse and get the detected format
List<String[]> parsedRows = parser.parseAll(new File("/path/to/input.csv"));
CsvFormat detectedFormat = parser.getDetectedFormat();

//now, write using the detected format:
CsvWriterSettings writerSettings = new CsvWriterSettings();
writerSettings.setFormat(detectedFormat);

CsvWriter writer = new CsvWriter(new File("/path/to/output.csv"), writerSettings);
writer.writeStringRowsAndClose(parsedRows);
```

Disclosure: I'm the author of this library. It's open-source and free (Apache 2.0 license)

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to read the wholes lines to check if it's an embedded-quotes-file or not. If you trust your inputs, then you'll just have to check the first line (or the second one if your first line is the column definition).

For this line, check if it begins and ends with the double quotes (check the first and last character of the line as String).

You can stop here if you still trust your inputs enough, or count the number of "," (not just commas, the quote-comma-quote structure, without spaces I guess) and compare it with the number of row you csv file should have (minus one), if it's a fixed value.

If it's not a fixed value per line, your solution should work, because anyway normaly, no CSV should have commas as content (like the "Hello, world" example OldCurmudgeon gave in comment).

But then again, it depends more on how much you trust your csv to be well formatted, and you'd better be sure to detect abnormal input before they go further.